# Should we use "lay" or "lays" in this context?

Tags: tenses, lie-lay-lain-laid

I found this sentence in [Longman dictionary](http://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/crux):

> The crux of the problem **lay** in the lack of equipment.

I think it should be "**lays**" instead of "**lay**", but even when I googled, I noticed there are more results for "lay" than are for "lays" in this context. Could you please explain which one is correct?

Answer (score 2):

The correct answer for past tense is 'lay', as Longman tells you. You could use 'lies' as a correct alternative for the present tense.

Answer (score 0):

Two irregular verbs that are often confused:

- lay laid laid - German: leg-en legte gelegt
- lie lay lain - German: lieg-en lag gelegen

You can lie in bed.
You can lay a child in the bed.